# What do most programmers do to review css changes without having to delete the cache of the browser?

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I'm working on a website, I check the changes on my browser (Google Chrome), and since usually the browser doesn't register the changes I make into the CSS file, I usually just work into an incognito window to avoid the hassle of deleting the cache manually. The downside is that I have to close it and open it often, and I have to log again in the app I'm working on every single time.
This is relatively quickly but it adds up over time when done hundreds of times.

There has to be a better way. What do most programers do?

Comment: I'm using a sandbox server which is not caching. But when working live I use the ?version trick.

Comment: The better way _is_ to just clear the cache via Ctrl+F5. No restarting the app or incognito windows needed.

Answer (score 2):

On the **network** tab of the developer tool in google chrome, you should be able to disable cache (the highlighted box). The setting will be saved and automatically applied every time you use google chrome.

[image: Sanjay Ghemawat]

Comment: Same in Firefox and other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get the browser to reload external `css` files, is to 'trick' the browser into interpretting the `link` to the file as having changed. This is achieved by adding a query string to the reference to the file in the `html` head and modifying it each time you want to reload.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/styles.css?v1">
```

will always load `styles.css` regardless of whatever follows the '?' but the browser parses the `href` attribute as having changed.

You just change the query string and save the `html` file each time.

Answer (score 0):

I actually use a plugin that clears the cache from the site i am currently on when i hit the F9 button.
At least on Firefox, the "clear cache" on the network tab doesn't always seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind reloading cache for your site only, I often press `ctrl+f5` (or for mac users, `cmd+shift+r`), which refreshes the page, and cache on the specific page youre on.